# Regex / Remove slash from string in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub, slash

Thanks in advance...

I am having some trouble with regular expressions in ruby, or otherwise finding a way to remove a slash from a string.  Here is how my string looks:

```
string = "word \/ word"
```

I am trying to remove both the backslash and the slash; I want this result:

```
string = "word  word"
```

I think I am missing something with escape characters, or who knows what!

I have tried this:

```
string.gsub(/\//, "")
```

which will remove the backslash, but leaves the slash.  I have tried variations with escape characters all over and in places that don't even make sense!

I am terrible with regex and get very frustrated working with strings in general, and I am just at a loss.  I'm sure it's something obvious, but what am I missing?

Comment: `string.gsub(/\/|\\/,"")` will remove both slashes, but as Niklas B points out, you are better using string replace.

Comment: there's actually only one slash in the string because the first one is an unnecessary escape slash

Comment: Not an actual answer, but you can use alternate regex syntax, something like `string.gsub(%r!\\/!, '')` to ease the pain of the 'how many times do i escape this?' question.

Comment: Am I missing something? Where is Niklas B answer?

Comment: doesnt work on this one: a = "/a/\a\a\\/a\a/a\/a/\a/\a"

Answer (score 5):

The reason why is because both `/` and `\` are not valid characters in a Regexp on their own. So they must be escaped by putting a `\` before them. So `\` becomes `\\` and `/` become `\/`. Putting these together inside another set of slashes to make a Regexp literal, we get:

```
string.gsub(/\\\//, "")
```

Another way to write this is:

```
string.gsub(/#{Regexp.escape('\/')}/, "")
```

You should check out rubular for a nice way to develop Regexp strings.

http://rubular.com/r/ml1a9Egv4B

Comment: However, I prefer Niklas B.'s solution below since it doesn't even use a Regexp.

Comment: You can write the regexp without interpolation: `string.gsub(Regexp.escape("\/"), '')`.

Comment: Actually that doesn't do the same thing, @steenslag. First off, I want to point out I had an error in my answer (which I've edited). The string `'\/'` needs to be in single quotes so that Ruby doesn't unescape it to `/`. Next, `Regexp.escape` returns a string, so your example is just doing this: `string.gsub('/', '')` which is not what you intended. Instead, you should either directly supply a string, or use `Regexp.escape` interpolated inside an actual Regexp. Hopefully that all made sense!

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "word \/ word"
p str.delete('\/') #=>"word  word"
# to get rid of the double spaces:
p str.delete('\/').squeeze(' ') #=>"word word"
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Very nice @steenslag, I wasn't familiar with the squeeze method....exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does what you want but not for the reasons you think:

```
string = "word \/ word"
# => "word / word"
string.gsub(/\//, "")
# => "word  word"
```

**Note:** you need gsub! if you want to replace the contents of string